# Does cuckoo hash map implemented in DPDK support parallel lookup with AVX512?

Tags: dpdk

DPDK has added AVX512 support but does cuckoo hash map implemented in DPDK support parallel batch lookup with that? Or it is just doing the batch lookup in a more efficient serial fashion? This is part of the documentation that confused me.

> Also, the API contains a method to allow the user to look up entries
> in batches, achieving higher performance than looking up individual
> entries, as the function prefetches next entries at the time it is
> operating with the current ones, which reduces significantly the
> performance overhead of the necessary memory accesses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the latest code available in [memcmp for cuckoo hash](https://git.dpdk.org/dpdk/tree/lib/librte_hash/rte_cmp_x86.h), there are no signs for AVX512 `zmm` register calls. Instead, there are SIMD intrinsics for minimum compatibility for SSE for core `memcmp` functions.

based on the `gcc` or `clang` compiler with DPDK option set for AVX512, other parts of cuckoo library might get converted to AVX512. But core memcmp is SSE (128bits).

Comment: @UnderCover if the answer has explained how AVX512 is not getting used, please accept and upvote.